Vertex AI: Automl-tabular template keeps giving me an error
I am trying to use Google's AutoML product (VertexAI) to build a machine learning model.
I successfully uploaded my data set - see image below.

However, when I try to create a pipeline run using the AutoML template for tabular regression, the pipeline fails. I will show the steps on VertexAI, I just use default settings without changing anything:





The first pipeline I ran failed.


I pasted the debugging json into ChatGPT. It told me to try change the machine types from n1-standard-8 or n1-highmem-8 to n1-standard-4. I tried this, but pipeline still failing. I have also ensured that the compute service has the right settings enabled.


Hi @alitkie, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
